# Wordpress content type issue

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, .htaccess

i have just moved my site form one host to the other one and have some issue with the links on the site. Some of the links does not work and when i click them it is opening download windows.
What i saw in console log is that

```
Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/x-httpd-php
```

What should be the content type and where to fix i? in htaccess? Or it is a host problem?

Comment: Can you just check your default in parmalink.

Comment: I do not understand. What you mean? 
i have category/short-stories/ which does not work and opening download window that i mention above
 and category/movie which works correctly and goes to the href="mysite.com/category/short-stories/ 

Just to notice that it works on the old host.

Comment: The cms admin panel also does not work. Again i have download window 
and when i download the file. Here is the content of the file

``define('WP_USE_THEMES', true);
/** Loads the WordPress Environment and Template */
require( dirname( __FILE__ ) . '/wp-blog-header.php' );``